# Declaring New Form variable type VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to show multiple forms equal, first declare a variable of type Form, then set the variable a name, then display it but I can not have success.

It dont show any new window.

```
Dim from_var As New Form
from_var = inventory_stat_item

With from_var
    .MdiParent = main
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    .Show()
End With
```

**UPDATE:**
The variable `from_var` shall have the following forms names: (inventory_stat_item | inventory_edit_item | inventory_new_item)

Comment: Are the `Forms` that you are adding to from_var already been created?

Comment: That's right, I am just declaring that form within the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want as long as you are creating and newing the `Forms` before hand. Something like this quick and dirty example.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim inventory_stat_item As Form2 = New Form2
    Dim inventory_edit_item As Form3 = New Form3
    Dim inventory_new_item As Form4 = New Form4
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        showForms(inventory_edit_item)
        showForms(inventory_new_item)
        showForms(inventory_stat_item)

    End Sub

    Private Sub showForms(from_var As Form)
        With from_var
            .MdiParent = Me
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            .Show()

        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Every you called `New inventory_stat_item` they created new object reference.

You must split your code

Called once(ex: When form load)

```
Dim from_var As New inventory_stat_item
```

Called when user click something

```
With from_var
    .MdiParent = Me
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    .Show()
End With
```